# BroadcastReceiver setting own context

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

is is possible to set own context after creating broadcastreceiver like this:?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment(){

Button myButton;

@Override
 onCreate {
  myButton = (Button) findview...
  myButton.setOnClickListner(myListener);
}
 .
 .
 .

MyListener {
@Override
OnClickListner {
  MyBroadCastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadCastReceiver()
  receiver.setContext(mContext)
  }
}    
    public static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     Context mContext;

     void setContext(Context context) {
      mContext = context;
     }

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (mContext!= null){
        log.d(TAG, "Context not null")
      }
    }
```

}

Every time method onReceive is invoked my mContext is null, is there any solution for that?

Comment: can you please tell what you wanna do with that context? open an activity or something ?

Comment: sure, I'd like to use DialogFragment, that's why I try to get context related to Activity.

Comment: Please tell us why you need the activity context.  Generally speaking, you can't assume the Activity still exists when the receiver is called, so you can't safely pass it an activity context.  That's why its passed its own.  The sole exception being when the receiver is registerd and unregistered within the activity, and then its usually an annonymous subclass that just access the activity as needed.

Comment: Gabe Sechan thanks for replay,
I forget to wrote it.
MyBroadcastReceiver is inner class of Fragment, and it only exist (is registerd and unregistered) while this fragment exist.

Comment: I agree with Gabe, but if you still want to handle this way then try passing value to Intent and you can open whatever you get their  eg. if you want to open Mainactivity and its method pass it in intent, i know it is not good way but it may work

Comment: @Nimdokai then you can use `getActivity()` but be sure on null checking.

Comment: @Enzokie I can't call getActivity() on context from receiver, only             context.getApplicationContext() is available.

Comment: @Nimdokai I mean `MyFragment.this.getActivity()` since your `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class right?

Comment: @Enzokie right, but do you mean to use MyFragment.this.getActivity() in onReceive in BroadCastReceiver?

Comment: @Nimdokai ok since your `BroadcastReceiver` is `static` which I thought *non static* at first then you cannot do that way. However you can put it in `receiver.setContext(MyFragment.this.getActivity())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with declaring receiver in manifest, while it should be declared only in fragment, after changing it, everything works as it should.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

**try this my friend**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Context mContext;

         public MyReceiver() {
        super();
       }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mContext = context;
            if (mContext != null) {
                log.d(TAG, "Context not null")
            }else{
            log.d(TAG, "  null Context ")
               }
        }
    }
```

create new object of your broadcast like this

```
MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver(this);
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for replay, but this will only change mContext to context from onReceive method parameter, I don't want this context, I really need Activity Context.

Comment: than call your bradcast from activity and pass e.g MainActivity.this as context

Comment: When I was trying to do so, I get messages that BroadCastReceiver must have default constructor.

Comment: as I understand, you advise to create two constructors:
1. default, which call super()
2. with context as parameter
right?

Comment: yup bro @Nimdokai

Comment: did it work for you...???? it is work in my case when i m trying with to check auto Internet connection checking.

Comment: unfortunately not, i get RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.mypackage.MyBroadCastReceiver java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void com.mypackage.MyBroadCastReceiver.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.ActivityThread>

Comment: please paste your whole code where you create broadcast object